# How to force ApproximateReceiveCount to be 1?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I am using SQS in a java spring boot project in the following way:

```
@Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
        factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(1);
        factory.setWaitTimeOut(20);
        return factory;
    }
```

I'm getting unordered data and have checked the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` logs and it seems that when `ApproximateReceiveCount = 2` I'm getting unordered data. I thought that by setting `factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(1);` I would only be getting 1 message and then `ApproximateReceiveCount = 2` would not be possible and its value would only ever be 1. Is there a way of enforcing the `ApproximateReceiveCount` to be 1? Could I do it by setting `setMaxNumberOfMessages` or should it be done differently?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a FIFO queue?

The standard SQS queue is unordered by default so you can't influence message order from your application.

Create a FIFO queue and see if you are still getting unordered messages.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html